# chrome is not working as expected while unloading the page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, google-chrome

i have an orders page in which the admin selects the orders . selected orders are stored and updated in database after regular interval using jquery. if after selecting checkboxes a user leaves the page i want to give him a confirm message. this is not working with chrome. as chrome onbeforeunload event requires a return string. it is blocking all alerts and confirm boxes while unloading the page.how can i get the action whether user wants to stay on page ( .. // do nothing ) leaves the page ( // updates the table ) 
please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script>
window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
  //alert('Dialog text here.') Wrong//
  return 'Dialog text here.';
};
</script>
```

It should be written as this. According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.onbeforeunload)

I have try different method, finally I get this:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        //do something
        alert('You stay!!')
    },500);
    return 'Dialog text here.';
}
```

Comment: thanks for the help i have tried it . i dont want it to return a string i want to show a confirm box so i may know whether user want to stay on page or not :(

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.onbeforeunload states

> Since 25 May 2011, the HTML5 specification states that calls to window.showModalDialog(), window.alert(), window.confirm(), and window.prompt() methods may be ignored during this event.

You can't do anything once the user has chosen to leave the page. An AJAX call would not be guaranteed to be called before the page is navigated away. So if the user confirms to leave, you have lost them. You could change the warning to persuade them to stay and click a `Save` or `Confirm` button manually on your page before leaving.